# docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed

Tags: centos, docker

I'm running into this error while running even an official docker image such as OpenJDK or even hello-world:

```
# docker run hello-world
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed:
container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:402:
getting the final child's pid from pipe caused: EOF: unknown.
```

My OS is:

```
# rpm --query centos-release
centos-release-7-5.1804.4.el7.centos.x86_64
```

and my Docker version:

```
# docker -v
Docker version 20.10.14, build a224086
```

The error appears for no change or update.
How can I investigate the reason of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

CentOS 7 default kernel (3.10) has some problems with the latest Docker releases.
It needs to be updated to kernel version 5+.

https://forums.docker.com/t/centos7-docker-hello-world-fails/68941/4

> I use CentOS 7.6, but the kernel version was 3.10. So, I’ve seen the same message after I update the docker-ce version Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962. To solve this, I updated the kernel version to 4.20, then docker works well. I’ve followed the process to update the kernel in CentOS in this page.

Useful links for CentOS kernel update:

- https://medium.com/@nazishalam07/update-centos-kernel-3-10-to-5-13-latest-9462b4f1e62c
- https://www.tecmint.com/install-upgrade-kernel-version-in-centos-7/